# assertequals in junit test

Tags: java, junit

I have the method:

```
public void addDepartment(String[] list, Department department) {
    if(list[0]!=null && list[0]!=""){
    department.setDepName(list[0]);
    this.departmentDao.addOrEditDepartment(department);
    }
}
```

and I have made a test case for it which is ..

```
public void testAddDepartment(){
    Department department = new Department();
    String[] list = new String[1];
    list[0] = "mmm";
    department.setDepId(120);
    department.setDepName(list[0]);
    service.addDepartment(list, department);
    assertEquals("mmm",service.getDepartment(120).getDepName());

    //assertNotNull(service.getDepartment(112).getDepName());

}
```

but an error in assertequals appears which is assertequal is not a function(string,void ).. but I don't know how to test it .. any help plzz?

Comment: yesss of course .. i think i mis test the void method

Answer (score 2):

The method `assertEquals` check for the identity of two objects.

Here you are checking between:

- `department`
- the result of the call to `service.addDepartment(list, department)`

but the method `addDepartment` returns `void`, so is not usable in this method.

---

Probably you would like to do something like the following:

```
@Test
public void testAddDepartment(){
    Department department = new Department();
    String[] list = new String[1];
    list[0] = "mmm";
    department.setDepId(120);
    department.setDepName(list[0]);
    service.addDepartment(list, department);

    // Probably you need to change this to what you like to test
    assertArrayEquals(list, service.getListNotShownHere());

}
```

Comment: @mermer it depends on what you like to test.

Comment: i like to test the add department method :) .. i mean when adding

Comment: @mermer I reckon that your problem is in service.getDepartment(120),  can u add the code of this method?